# Javascript tooltip positioning issue

Tags: javascript, popup

I would like to create a javascript popup using following script.

```
var xOffset = 30;
var yOffset = -5;

function showPopup (targetObjectId, eventObj) {
    var newXCoordinate = (eventObj.pageX)?eventObj.pageX + xOffset:eventObj.x + xOffset + ((document.body.scrollLeft)?document.body.scrollLeft:0);
    var newYCoordinate = (eventObj.pageY)?eventObj.pageY + yOffset:eventObj.y + yOffset + ((document.body.scrollTop)?document.body.scrollTop:0);
    moveObject(targetObjectId, newXCoordinate, newYCoordinate);

    -----etc
}



function moveObject(objectId, newXCoordinate, newYCoordinate) {
    // get a reference to the cross-browser style object and make sure the object exists
    var styleObject = getStyleObject(objectId);
    if(styleObject) {

//      newXCoordinate = newXCoordinate-8;
//      newYCoordinate = newYCoordinate-300;

        styleObject.left = newXCoordinate;
        styleObject.top = newYCoordinate;
        return true;
    } else {
        // we couldn't find the object, so we can't very well move it
        return false;
    }
} // moveObject
```

Demo here:

http://jsfiddle.net/jkdYr/

Popup will show successfully but, its positioning becomes an issue. Popup not getting dynamic position according to cursor move. Anybody can please help to change the above script to show popup position according to cursor position.
ie, normally popup attach to bottom of element; if there is not enough space at bottom popup should attach top

Thanks

Comment: can you provide e demo in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: added a demo in jsfiddle. thanks

Comment: Where u hv added the scrips  ? cant see it , but the function is calling..

Comment: added two external java script file under manage resources

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need:

```
<li id="list-item" onclick="return !showPopup('product_deatils_2', event);">
    <a href="javascript:;">Product2</a>
    <div onclick="event.cancelBubble = true;" class="popup" id="product_deatils_2"><a href="javascript:;" onclick="hideCurrentPopup(); return false;" title="close" class="popupLink">[x]</a> Popup Text  
    </div>
</li>
```

and in your JS use something like this:

```
$("#list-item").click(function (e) {
    $("#product_deatils_2").css("margin-left",e.offsetX);
    $("#product_deatils_2").css("margin-top",e.offsetY); 
});
```

Let me know if it helps :)

Comment: thank you for your response. unfortunately the issue not yet fixed :-(

Answer (score 0):

Please check this. Is this tht ur looking fr?

http://jsfiddle.net/jkdYr/5/

I just modified the functions like

```
function showPopup(elementN, event){
    $("#"+elementN).css({
        "display":"block",
        "top":event.pageY+"px" ,
        "left":event.pageX+"px"    
    })
}
function hideCurrentPopup(ele){
    $(ele).parent().hide();
}
```

if you dont use jquery then also it can be simply implemented in pure js.

Comment: this is also don't get dynamic position for tooltip. if we have add one more list item we need to scroll window for view popup :-(

Comment: yes ,if the content goes beyond the window height you need to scroll down. Or Wht you want to do at that case?

Comment: In that case I would like to show popup just reverse order ie, popup move to top instead of bottom